# Match everything between optional single or double quotation marks

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm developing a regex to parse values out of a JSON response but I'm having trouble with one field because it contains human-written text so, as the content can vary and break the regex, I need a regex that will match all of the following potential values:

```
, 'resolve_comment': "This value's comment contains an apostrophe / single quotation mark so it will be automatically enclosed in double quotation marks", 
, 'resolve_comment': 'Some comments, like this one, contain a comma. If there is no comment then there will be no quotation marks as you can see below.', 
, 'resolve_comment': None,
```

None of the regexps I've found online have worked for all 3 of these scenarios.

The closest I've gotten was:

1. `'resolve_comment': (?:(?:"(?P<resolve_comment>[^"]*)")|(?:'(?P<resolve_comment>[^']*)')|(?P<resolve_comment>None)),`  but the system doesn't allow duplicated capture group names.
2. `'resolve_comment': (?:(?:"([^"]*)")|(?:'([^']*)')|(None)),` but that created 3 capture groups of which only one was populated.
3. `'resolve_comment': ["|']?(.*)["|']?,` but that leaves a trailing quotation mark which isn't ideal.

Comment: What is the "system"?

Comment: The system that's doing the parsing is Splunk.

Comment: What about `'resolve_comment':\s*(?P<resolve_comment>"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|None),` and then just replace the first and last quotes with `| eval text = replace(text,"^['\"]|['\"]$", "")` (or with `resolve_comment`)? Splunk has no branch reset group anyway and you cannot use identically named groups either

Comment: Thanks but maybe I should have further clarified that the parsing is being done as part of the Field Extraction stage for a custom add-on, not a search where I can use functions.

Comment: If a conditional construct is supported, you could capture that into Group 2 with https://regex101.com/r/Z3ZKg2/1.

Comment: I see that that regex works on that site but, unfortunately, Splunk rejects it with error `The regular expression is not valid`.

Comment: Then you can't solve it with regex alone. You need identically named capturing groups support.

Comment: Threre exists two consecitive `,` Is that correct? Also: It would be helpful to see how does the end of 'resolve_comment' end. What's behind the last 'resolve_comment'?

Comment: @Julio One at the start and one at the end, yes. Just another KV pair.

Comment: So what's behind the last KV pair?

Answer (score 0):

this is my regex and it matches all your potential values, try this:

```
(?<=").*(?=")|(?<=').*(?=')|None
```

so i am matching everything between " " and ' ' and also the value None.
It doesn't match strings like ' " considering that to be invalid here.
see it here: https://regex101.com/r/yV9GES/1

tell me if you were looking for something else?

Comment: The first example's apostrophe breaks this regex. Thanks, though.

Comment: i tried and it seems to work here : https://regex101.com/r/yV9GES/2

Comment: Yes, it works when only the value is present but the entire text is present so `'resolve_comment'` breaks it.

Comment: ok...you want to include 'resolve_comment' as well..sorry, i misread. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Try this: `'resolve_comment': (?:["|']?(.*)["|']|(None))` /gm .It should work.

Comment: That does work but has a similar problem to #2 of my own in that it always creates an empty capture group.